# How to extract co-authors from a Google Scholar page

Tags: javascript, api, url, dom, web-scraping

I'm trying to **scrape** the names of co-authors from the Google Scholar page https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=m8dFEawAAAAJ using JavaScript.

All the co-authors for a publication are visible only after clicking the publication link. A popup page then shows the co-authors. But, doing this for every publication is very time-costly.
I can't even get the data using axios on a publication link, such as https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=m8dFEawAAAAJ&citation_for_view=m8dFEawAAAAJ:-f6ydRqryjwC , which gives a CORS* error.

How to fetch the co-author names in an efficient way?

[Note: The co-authors are listed below each publication as shown in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be9vA.png)

Comment: Please read [mre]. We need the smallest sample of HTML and code that demonstrates the problem in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood with your question is that you wanted to get names of all the Co-authors listed on the right side of the page. Right? Here is my solution to get all of their names.

First all of their details in inside an `<li>` tag, and all of those li tags are inside an `<ul class="gsc_rsb_a">`. So, what you had to do, create object for all of the `<li>` using `const list=document.querySelectorAll(".gsc_rsb_a li")` command.

Next phase is to get `textContent` form multiple `<span>` inside those li tags. See, spans have details for all of the Co-authors and there are three of them. First one will return empty string if we used `textContent`  property, second one is consist of name, designantion, place, e-mail id and third one has only designation and place. What I did is extract name form second one. This is done by using multiple properties `indexOf()` and `slice()`. And last thing is to `push()` their names into an array.

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll(".gsc_rsb_a li");
var slicedName = new Array(); //Array to save names
var description; //To store third span details 
var descriptionAndName; //To store second span details
var index;

for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
 description = list[i].querySelectorAll("span")[2].textContent //will get discription of authors
 descriptionAndName = list[i].querySelectorAll("span")[1].textContent //will get discription + name
 index = descriptionAndName.indexOf(description);
 slicedName.push(descriptionAndName .slice(0,index));
}
```

***Above solution isn't the questioner's requirement, sorry for the inconvenience!!***
***Next solution might fulfil it!***

Names can be accessed without opening the pop-up window, their names are mentioned under the title. All you have to do is extract their names form that tag.

Below code might help you with that.

```
var authors=document.querySelectorAll(".gs_gray"); //selecting all the names into an object
var authorName=new Array();

for(var i=0;i<authors.length;i+=2){
  authorName.push(authors[i].textContent);
}
```

This code will save multiple names (if article was written by multiple people) into an single element.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your answer, but I'm trying to extract the co-authors for EACH PUBLICATION as in the question. Please refer to the picture for getting a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Each publication title contains a javascript link triggering the popup and loading of additional html content (including authors).

Rather than try to figure out the XHR requests, you can use a browser extension to scrape the javascript rendered content. I've identified

- navigation CSS selectors for "show more" button, open popup details, close popup
- content CSS selectors for publication title, authors, year, journal/book.

Based on these selectors, using the open source scrape extension https://github.com/get-set-fetch/extension I've created a scrape scenario.

"eLtI4gnavZVhS8MwEIb/yuFAFEy3KYIMpvhBBT8Jfh2ENEmbaJaE5rr587222m44sEOwUGjIey/p3T2XXvoUQuk0vEoTnKjgpc6dlW1fpR+EKI3CUtkgDipwNmGPjkGMaTGdps4uK1v3TIb1VFrsbO+MW2p/WtMRl+sb9fggtvf0PO9jV2pkid6iYYR9b9BHJaJmqoOADX37F0Zn/wDlbj9MyiR5Hgu4hbxGpCROIJmwhZbGHP3Ko8oakeBIIjEQegEhap+gK0WCGGIdV54c+VrxJsdMwd6KfTTRLiTdq0dhPr+e/Ub6WNj2WBtpOpatNk0bqThadJo769/pf9tFm5avzWbcAGl5km7h0TBprFNn83PoDTbC1c0sFDUa8h4RfXkgehcNJXDMIa4O2FC5C13RpaEhVPBGufLCnRwxHo4bB5/zEHAg"

Inside the extension do: new project > config hash > paste the above hash (without the quotes) > save, scrape, view results > export as csv.

Disclaimer: I'm the extension author.

Comment: Please read "[Link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)" and "[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/153968)". While you have additional content the gist of your answer lives behind the link, which, if it rots and disappears, will render your answer worthless.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all co-authors using `axios` and `cheerio`. The code below shows how you can do this. Check [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Google-Scholar-Authors-NodeJS-SerpApi#index.js).

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require("axios");

const AXIOS_OPTIONS = {
  headers: {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36",
  },
};

const BASE_URL = "https://scholar.google.com";

const userID = "m8dFEawAAAAJ";

function getAuthorsInfo() {
  return axios(`${BASE_URL}/citations?hl=en&user=${userID}`, AXIOS_OPTIONS).then(async ({ data }) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);

    const link = $("#gsc_cods_urls").attr("data-lc");

    return axios(BASE_URL + link, AXIOS_OPTIONS).then(({data}) => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(data);
      
      return Array.from($(".gs_ai_name a")).map((el) => $(el).text().trim());
    })
  });
}

getAuthorsInfo().then(console.log);
```

Outputs:

```json
[
   "Christoph Benzmüller",
   "Pascal Fontaine",
   "Stephan Merz",
   "Tomer Libal",
   "David Deharbe",
   "John Slaney",
   "Dale Miller",
   "Herman Geuvers",
   "Joseph Boudou",
   "Giselle Reis",
   "Mikheil Rukhaia",
   "Martin Riener",
   "Leon Weber",
   "Jan Gorzny",
   "Oswaldo Duarte Miranda",
   "JCN de Araujo",
   "Odylio D Aguiar",
   "Annika Kanckos",
   "Carlos HC Ribeiro",
   "Joubert de Castro Lima",
   "Ekaterina Lebedeva"
]
```

Alternatively, you can use the [Google Scholar Author API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-author-api) from SerpApi. SerpApi is a free API with 100 searches per month. If you need more searches, there are paid plans.

The difference is that you won't have to write code from scratch and maintain it. You may also experience blocking from Google thus you need to understand how to bypass blocks from Google, changing selectors which would break the parser. Instead, you just need to iterate the structured JSON and get the data you wan. [Check out the playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?engine=google_scholar_author&author_id=m8dFEawAAAAJ&hl=en).

Usage:

```js
const SerpApi = require("google-search-results-nodejs");
const search = new SerpApi.GoogleSearch(process.env.API_KEY); //your api key from serpapi.com

const params = {
  engine: "google_scholar_author",                      // search engine
  hl: "en",                                             // parameter defines the language to use for the Google search
  author_id: "m8dFEawAAAAJ",                            // Parameter defines the ID of an author. You can find the ID either by using our Google Scholar Profiles API or by going to the Google Scholar user profile page and getting it from there (e.g., https://scholar.google.com/citations?user={author_id}).
  view_op: "list_colleagues",                           // Parameter is used for viewing specific parts of a page. "list_colleagues" - to view all co-authors
};

const getAuthorsInfo = ({ co_authors }) => {
  return co_authors.map((el) => el.name)
};

const getJson = (params) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    search.json(params, resolve);
  })
}

getJson(params).then(getAuthorsInfo).then(console.log)
```

Outputs:

```json
[
   "Christoph Benzmüller",
   "Pascal Fontaine",
   "Stephan Merz",
   "Tomer Libal",
   "David Deharbe",
   "John Slaney",
   "Dale Miller",
   "Herman Geuvers",
   "Joseph Boudou",
   "Giselle Reis",
   "Mikheil Rukhaia",
   "Martin Riener",
   "Leon Weber",
   "Jan Gorzny",
   "Oswaldo Duarte Miranda",
   "JCN de Araujo",
   "Odylio D Aguiar",
   "Annika Kanckos",
   "Carlos HC Ribeiro",
   "Joubert de Castro Lima",
   "Ekaterina Lebedeva"
]
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.